# Slider error with thumbnails in chrome

Tags: html, css, slider, compatibility

I'm using a slider in HTML and CSS3 for a website but, with Chrome I can't see the thumbnails and with IE 9 the thumbnails appear. I've checked the code but I didn't find the issue.

Here the CODE

**HTML**

```
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px; height: 480px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 240px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images%20(2).jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images%20(2).jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images%20(1).jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="/page/bioedilizia/img/images%20(1).jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; left: 248px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin 02 Begin -->
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; height: 480px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 99px; height: 66px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                <div class=c>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">jquery content slider</a>
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

**CSS**

```
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l              (normal)
        .jssora05r              (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
        .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
        */
.jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
.jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
.jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
.jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 02 css */
            /*
            .jssort02 .p            (normal)
            .jssort02 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
            .jssort02 .pav          (active)
            .jssort02 .pav:hover    (active mouseover)
            .jssort02 .pdn          (mousedown)
            */
.jssort02 .w
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.jssort02 .c
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 62px;
    border: #000 2px solid;
}
.jssort02 .p:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav .c 
{
    border-width: 0px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 62px;
}
.jssort02 .p:hover .c, .jssort02 .pav:hover .c
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 97px;
    height: 64px;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It's not a properly error code, with IE I can see the images thumbnails with chrome I can't

Comment: Can you hook this fiddle up with the slider code that you are using? http://jsfiddle.net/hLrvyb01/

Comment: oh! yes, I'm so sorry i forgot them, there are 3 javascripts http://jsfiddle.net/hLrvyb01/3/ I've added 3 external resources

Comment: You added jssor javascript library, but the initializing javascript code is missing.

Comment: You are right, sorry but today i'm out. http://jsfiddle.net/hLrvyb01/5/ now i've update with the initializing javascript